# faster alternative to webclient / webdrive

Tags: webclient, webdav, web-client

I used webclient & webdrive to connect webdav server, webdrive is faster than webclient, but its not open source, and I require open source module to work on client for webdav server. kindly suggest me, if any one have the solution.

Or If any one know about speedup webclient as faster as webdrive.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason for having a requirement for Open Source?

One of the benefits of WebDrive is that the same engineering team has been working on the product regularly for nearly 15 years. For you, the end user, this means that any issues that may arise with the product are able to be quickly and efficiently addressed by a team of engineers who are well-versed with the source code.

Comment: I need it for one of my client, i dont want to configure webdav drive manually on each pc at client level, require open source for predefined configuration. few settings should be predifined with drive letter, client suppose to put webdav url link only and connect it.

Comment: WebDrive has an AppConfig.ini configuration file so that you can pre-configure WebDrive with the proper settings, then simply distribute the installer. When WebDrive installs, the mapped drive, URL, and protocol are all pre-configured. The user simply enters their username and password (which can then be saved to prevent re-entering on subsequent sessions).